# React Tabs refactoring to typescirpt and hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

https://jsfiddle.net/wg4uL2dk/
here is old example of Tabs component.
I tried to make it with function components and typescript.

```
interface ITabBarProps {
  children: React.ReactElement[]
}

export const TabBar = ({ children }: ITabBarProps) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0)

  const handleTabClick = (index: number) => {
    setActiveTab(index)
  }

  function renderTabNav () {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        onClick: handleTabClick,
        index: index,
        isActive: index === activeTab
      })
    })
  }

  const renderActiveTabContent = () => {
    if (children[activeTab]) {
      return children[activeTab].props.children
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {renderTabNav()}
      </div>
      <div>
        {renderActiveTabContent()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

interface ITabBarItemProps {
  label?: string
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export const Tab = ({ label }: ITabBarItemProps) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={cn(classes.tabBarNav)}
    >
      Button
    </button>
  )
}
```

onClick props is kinda doesn't work, and i don't get the point why.
in example i see how he get that prop 'onClick' and pass it to onClick of child element, but i don't know the approach to this problem.

quick note:
there is not exactly error. I expected the when i click on Tab Component it should do the handleTabClick arrow function from parrent component, but there is no result

Comment: What exactly is the error? "onClick props is kinda doesn't work" is not a clear description.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff there is not exactly error. I expected the when i click on Tab Component it should do the handleTabClick arrow function from parrent component, but there is no result